# Как удержать область просмотра при изменении размеров элементов

Tags: javascript, html, css

На странице происходят какие-то события итд...и в один из моментов какой-то элемент может поменять размер.

Вот пример кода:

```js
window.scroll(0,document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight)
```

```css
.exotic-element {
  padding: 20px;
  background: gray;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.exotic-element:hover {
  padding: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem placeat labore iure minima rerum voluptas in eveniet atque, necessitatibus voluptatum, laborum corporis adipisci saepe consequuntur. Doloribus repellendus obcaecati assumenda atque.</div>
<div>Rem, voluptas sequi qui nesciunt ex voluptatem, odit architecto, ad modi in blanditiis perferendis! Perspiciatis totam molestiae beatae, nemo ipsa assumenda maiores, eum eos, accusantium, ex sed odit mollitia deleniti.</div>
<div>Delectus quod culpa tempora odio laudantium vel, consequuntur vitae non doloremque doloribus. Molestiae, magni reprehenderit dolorem modi libero labore ad pariatur fugiat, quasi nostrum molestias harum, qui minima, repudiandae est!</div>
<div>Labore illum nisi delectus consectetur, accusamus eum, ad pariatur eligendi optio. Rem quos architecto officia, beatae pariatur cum at doloribus perferendis officiis, voluptatem, cumque odit laboriosam inventore molestiae. Exercitationem, porro.</div>
<div>Nemo, non. Rem ab nisi tempora sequi ipsa, facere voluptates, nihil reiciendis maiores aliquam est eligendi ex vel veritatis porro tempore libero debitis. Molestias, praesentium quas. Optio nobis placeat eius.</div>
<div>Illum est omnis numquam eveniet minima at exercitationem quae adipisci blanditiis expedita, quos ipsa ipsum odit consequatur veritatis quidem iure rem necessitatibus fugiat molestiae obcaecati? Eius, veritatis. Ex, voluptate, obcaecati.</div>
<div>Vel reprehenderit eveniet doloremque delectus, quidem doloribus blanditiis inventore officiis minima laborum. Officiis reprehenderit asperiores reiciendis rem rerum voluptas sunt, eum nesciunt repellat aspernatur veniam deleniti necessitatibus cumque assumenda dolorem.</div>
<div>Doloribus ex molestiae reiciendis laboriosam consequuntur voluptate, magni perferendis non iusto aliquam necessitatibus tenetur sapiente eos, ullam sint perspiciatis, dolor quae laborum eius. Tempora molestias iure est, distinctio quibusdam consectetur.</div>
<div>Facere, eaque similique quis odio necessitatibus cumque eos saepe, nulla consectetur id animi officia libero, officiis ullam magni. Minus blanditiis aut placeat, eius hic nihil ut laborum expedita maxime assumenda?</div>
<div>Fuga itaque reiciendis eligendi dolorem et laudantium, ipsam nemo, dolor fugit tempora nam molestias placeat fugiat voluptates ducimus accusamus, optio sunt, qui quasi distinctio quo quis! Commodi molestiae possimus veritatis?</div>
  <div class="exotic-element">Hover me</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum asperiores doloremque architecto sapiente totam accusantium cupiditate accusamus porro id, quam deserunt minus. Non dolorem quos cumque iste in et explicabo.</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g6cdzn1y/

Нужно удержать состояние просмотровщика в конце страницы несмотря на изменения на странице

Comment: а можно чуть поконкретнее, что именно вам нужно

Comment: удержать просмотровщик в положении прокручено до конца

Comment: т.е. при изменении документа - он как приклеенный к концу, но при этом проматывать пользователь может?

Comment: @Zhihar ну да все так.